# How rtf text interpretation in notepad++

Tags: notepad++, rgb, rtf

I wrote an rtf text and saw how notepad++ sees this text and get a code.
eg: `Public Funcion EndApp()` As Boolean

**Its conversion in notepad :**

```
\r\n{\\colortbl;\\red 0\\green 176\\blue 80;}
\\viewkinf\\uc1\\trpar\\lang103\\f0\\fs22\\Public Function\\cf1\\EndApp()\\cf0\\As Boolean
```

can I know which syntax recognize that "`EndApp()`" is written green, what cf1 and cf0 means

Answer (score 1):

\cf1 refers to the color with index 1 in the color table which is \red 0\green 176\blue 80.

\cf0 is the "Auto" color, which is represented by the first (empty) entry, terminated by ";", in the color table.

You need a RTF parser to extract this information. Microsoft has published the C code for a small RTF parser in the RTF specification.

Comment: but why there's blue 80 if the "EndApp()" is green, I just need how notepad++ knows what is the color of a certain word

Comment: @ivi you can test the RGB values (0, 176, 80) on http://www.rgbtohex.net/ - it shows a (dark) green color as result. About Notepad++: as far as I know Notepad++ does not "convert" the RTF to code, it just displays the raw RTF code contained in the RTF file

Comment: i am writing a code to change certain words color automatically using the rust language so I need to read the text as txt and give the certain words the specific rgb. Notepadd++ read the txt as a code.

Comment: So you need to create a modified RTF file, which uses different colors than the original? Please edit your question to make your application goal clearer.

Comment: I want to write a code that changes the color within it, which means the code written in Rust language contains the command to change to color in rtf